# How to bind two way data in pure javascript or vanilla js?

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me how to bind the data with HTML view from .js(model)

I have array of objects and want to bind that each object from array to  present in HTML page.

Here is the JSON data I want to bind

```
[{
    actor_1_name: "CCH Pounder",
    actor_2_name: "Joel David Moore",
    budget: "237000000",
    content_rating: "PG-13",
    country: "USA",
    director_name: "James Cameron",
    genres: "Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi",
    language: "English",
    movie_imdb_link: "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1",
    movie_title: "Avatar ",
    plot_keywords: "avatar|future|marine|native|paraplegic",
    title_year: "2009"
},
{
    actor_1_name: "Johnny Depp",
    actor_2_name: "Orlando Bloom",
    budget: "300000000",
    content_rating: "PG-13",
    country: "USA",
    director_name: "Gore Verbinski",
    genres: "Action|Adventure|Fantasy",
    language: "English",
    movie_imdb_link: "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0449088/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1",
    movie_title: "Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End ",
    plot_keywords: "goddess|marriage ceremony|marriage",
    title_year: "2007"
 }]
```

And my view snippet is as below

```
     <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1" target="_blank">movie_title</a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        content_rating
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    plot_keywords
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>title_year</span>
                    <span>language</span>
                    <span>country</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Director: </span>director_name
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Actor 1:</span> actor_1_name <br>
                    <span>Actor 2:</span> actor_2_name
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want to bind data from json object to div, in iteration.

Using javascript only, no jquery no angular framework.

We can achieve same thing using `ng-repeat` or `*ngFor` in angular.

Comment: Please remove your styling-related CSS classes and elements, they are just annoying to answer.

Comment: @connexo i've removed my custom css classes.

Comment: Why are you talking about a two way bind ? The question is only about a single way (js => html)

Comment: @blue112 i want to process further, for that i will be needing two way approach, As of now i've not posted that scenario

Comment: The json is really just a string, so while you could convert to a javascript object and bind to that, to update the json string, you'd have to do that manually.

Comment: Apply JSON property names to all your controls and write some listeners to bind data. Why are you avoiding frameworks?

Comment: @SumeshTG, i tried this scenario also, but may be i'm missing something. can you provide me useful approach?

Comment: check my updated answer, it might be the two-way data binding you were looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a very basic way of doing it. You need to make sure the template `variable` strings in the `div#template` exist only once in the template (because of the basic approach to simply replace strings).

```js
let data = [{
  "actor_1_name": "CCH Pounder",
  "actor_2_name": "Joel David Moore",
  "budget": "237000000",
  "content_rating": "PG-13",
  "country": "USA",
  "director_name": "James Cameron",
  "genres": "Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi",
  "language": "English",
  "movie_imdb_link": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1",
  "movie_title": "Avatar ",
  "plot_keywords": "avatar|future|marine|native|paraplegic",
  "title_year": "2009"
}, {
  "actor_1_name": "Johnny Depp",
  "actor_2_name": "Orlando Bloom",
  "budget": "300000000",
  "content_rating": "PG-13",
  "country": "USA",
  "director_name": "Gore Verbinski",
  "genres": "Action|Adventure|Fantasy",
  "language": "English",
  "movie_imdb_link": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0449088/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1",
  "movie_title": "Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End ",
  "plot_keywords": "goddess|marriage ceremony|marriageproposal|pirate|singapore",
  "title_year": "2007"
}]

const tpl = document.getElementById('template');
const content = document.getElementById('content');

for (const item of data) {
  let templateStr = tpl.innerHTML;
  let template = tpl.cloneNode(true);
  for (const prop in item) {
    templateStr = templateStr.replace(prop, item[prop]);
  }
  template.id = '';
  template.removeAttribute('hidden');
  content.appendChild(template);
  template.innerHTML = templateStr;
}
```

```html
<div id="template" hidden>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <a href="movie_imdb_link" target="_blank">movie_title</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      content_rating
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    plot_keywords
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>title_year</span>
    <span>language</span>
    <span>country</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="name">Director: </span>director_name
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Actor 1:</span> actor_1_name <br>
    <span>Actor 2:</span> actor_2_name
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: It is one way right?

Comment: thanks, it's working like charm. what if i want to implement two way binding? this scenario works great for one way binding

Comment: Two way binding would involve input elements, registering input listeners on those and writing back the values to `data`.

Comment: I was about to post the same answer, good work!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
    var my_data = [{
    "actor_1_name": "CCH Pounder",
    "actor_2_name": "Joel David Moore",
    "budget": "237000000",
    "content_rating": "PG-13",
    "country": "USA",
    "director_name": "James Cameron",
    "genres": "Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi",
    "language": "English",
    "movie_imdb_link": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1",
    "movie_title": "Avatar ",
    "plot_keywords": "avatar|future|marine|native|paraplegic",
    "title_year": "2009"
   }, 
   {
    "actor_1_name": "Johnny Depp",
    "actor_2_name": "Orlando Bloom",
    "budget": "300000000",
    "content_rating": "PG-13",
    "country": "USA",
    "director_name": "Gore Verbinski",
    "genres": "Action|Adventure|Fantasy",
    "language": "English",
    "movie_imdb_link": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0449088/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1",
    "movie_title": "Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End ",
    "plot_keywords": "goddess|marriage ceremony|marriage\
    proposal|pirate|singapore",
    "title_year": "2007"
   }];

   var parent = document.querySelector('body');

   Object.keys(my_data).forEach((object) => {
       var divSeperator = document.createElement('div');
       parent.appendChild(divSeperator);
       Object.keys(my_data[object]).forEach((movieKeyElement) => {
         var movieElement = document.createElement('p');
         movieElement.innerHTML = my_data[object][movieKeyElement];

         // Append a classname
         movieElement.classList.add('CLASSNAME');
         // Add a class Attribute and set its value
         movieElement.setAttribute('class', 'CLASSNAME');

         movieElement.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
         movieElement.addEventListener('input', () => {
            my_data[object][movieKeyElement] = movieElement.innerHTML;
         })
         divSeperator.appendChild(movieElement);
       });
   })
```

this should create elements and full them in with your JSON Values

I've also added functionality to change the JSON values based on the edits on the elements, this could be unsafe though and i'd suggest atleast making a copy and adding validation, though that is beyond the scope of this question

Comment: this will create new elements, no issues it will work, But i've some custom css classes also.i need to apply css to it, also that would be great if you provide solution for two way binding

Comment: @PrasannaSasne I have updated my answer to include classes and maybe even two-way data-binding.

Comment: i don't want to apply class name from js file, in the html file class names will be there. i haven't posted class names in HTML file in my question. but for each field class names are there